# JSON.NET deserialising where no member name is available

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, json.net

Using JSON.NET in a VB.NET forms application,  I'm consuming data from a 3rd party,  simplified JSON below

```
{
"Venue": {
    "ID": "ABDDF",
    "Name": "My Place",
    "Address": {
        "Address1": "London Road,",
        "Address2": "",
        "Town": "TEST TOWN",
        "County": "TEST",
        "Postcode": "PO1 1ST",
        "Country": "United Kingdom",
        "Region": "Europe"
    },
    "Directions": "Blah Blah Blah",
    "Images": {
        "/images/venueXXX/ABDDF/image1.jpg": "Image of Venue",
        "/images/venueXXX/ABDDF/image10.jpg": "Image of Venue",
        "/images/venueXXX/ABDDF/image2.jpg": "Image of Venue",
        "/images/venueXXX/ABDDF/image3.jpg": "Image of Venue",
        "/images/venueXXX/ABDDF/image4.jpg": "Image of Venue"
    },
    "Equipment": [
        {
            "ID": 8127,
            "VenueID": 1000,
            "EquipmentID": 12,
            "EquipmentName": "Secretarial",
            "MaxQuantity": 1,
            "ShowOnVenuePage": true
        },
        {
            "ID": 8128,
            "VenueID": 1000,
            "EquipmentID": 21,
            "EquipmentName": "Typing Services",
            "MaxQuantity": 1,
            "ShowOnVenuePage": true
        }
    ]
},
"ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "200",
    "Message": "OK"
}
}
```

All is going well as I have created classes to be populated with the JSON data, shown below.

I call JSON.net's JsonConvert to populate the class

```
Dim QueryResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Container)(responseFromServer)
```

However I now need to reference the images shown in the JSON, while the Equipment can be retrieved in to my class for equipment,  I can't fathom how to get JSON.Net to access the images as they are not in what I'd call named pairs.

So the questions is,  what should my class declaration look like to allow JSON.net to populate the images (or do I need to add a ?  Also,  for my reference,  what is the correct terminology for how the images are stored in this JSON?

```
Public Class VenueDirectoryResult
    Public Response As ResponseStatus
    Public ID As String
    Public Name As String
    Public Address As Address
    Public Directions As String
    Public Equipment As New List(Of Equipment)
End Class

Public Class Address
Public Property Address1() As String
    Get
        Return m_Address1
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_Address1 = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Address1 As String
Public Property Address2() As String
    Get
        Return m_Address2
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_Address2 = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Address2 As String
Public Property Town() As String
    Get
        Return m_Town
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_Town = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Town As String
Public Property County() As String
    Get
        Return m_County
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_County = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_County As String
Public Property Postcode() As String
    Get
        Return m_Postcode
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_Postcode = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Postcode As String
Public Property Country() As String
    Get
        Return m_Country
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_Country = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Country As String
Public Property Region() As String
    Get
        Return m_Region
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_Region = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Region As String
End Class

Public Class Equipment
Public Property ID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_ID
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_ID = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_ID As Integer
Public Property VenueID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_VenueID
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_VenueID = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_VenueID As Integer
Public Property EquipmentID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_EquipmentID
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_EquipmentID = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_EquipmentID As Integer
Public Property EquipmentName() As String
    Get
        Return m_EquipmentName
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_EquipmentName = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_EquipmentName As String
Public Property MaxQuantity() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_MaxQuantity
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_MaxQuantity = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_MaxQuantity As Integer
Public Property ShowOnVenuePage() As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_ShowOnVenuePage
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        m_ShowOnVenuePage = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_ShowOnVenuePage As Boolean
Public Property Price() As System.Nullable(Of Double)
    Get
        Return m_Price
    End Get
    Set(value As System.Nullable(Of Double))
        m_Price = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Price As System.Nullable(Of Double)
Public Property Vatable() As System.Nullable(Of Boolean)
    Get
        Return m_Vatable
    End Get
    Set(value As System.Nullable(Of Boolean))
        m_Vatable = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Vatable As System.Nullable(Of Boolean)
End Class
```

Added Response Class

```
Public Class ResponseStatus
Public Property ErrorCode() As String
    Get
        Return m_ErrorCode
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_ErrorCode = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_ErrorCode As String
Public Property Message() As String
    Get
        Return m_Message
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_Message = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Message As String
End Class
```

And this is the container class

```
Public Class Container
    Public Venue As VenueDirectoryResult
End Class
```

Comment: Where is the definition for `ResponseStatus` class? Or is it the `HttpResponse.Status` property?

Comment: Have just added that to the end,  I over simplified my example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle the images, you can add the following to your `VenueDirectoryResult` class:

```
Public Images As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

You can get the list of images by examining the `Keys` collection from the dictionary.

As far as terminology, the images are being stored in a JSON object.  The object's property names are being used here to hold the the image URLs.